# Oracle.dataaccess dependencies on tfs build controller

Tags: oracle, build-automation, odp.net

How to solve issues of installed stuff that my solution depends on? 
I have a problem with oracle data access in my build controller: it says that it can't load Oracle.DataAccess or one of its dependencies.

So should I install ODAC on the build controller machine or copy dlls from program files ? Or anything else?

The problem exists only for the asp.net web site project, this project got no code, just global.asax and dependencies for other projects in solution, if I remove it from the build it's all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend installing the dlls as normal.  This way if you do any unit testing or whatnot all will work out-of-the-box.

--That would be the main argument for having it installed.

Otherwise, you will reduce Build controller maintenance and such if you copy over the dlls.

It's pretty much a similar argument that they detail here (sans licensing cost which don't exists for ODAC)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx